# I would like to find the sha1sum of a http response in android and checking that shasum result with manual one

Tags: android, sha1

Http URL: https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md
To find SHA1SUM from my system: Manually getting the response from the postman url and placing the response in a file and then Using the following command (linux)

sha1sum filename

From android code: After getting the http sync call response,passing that string to the following method.

```
public static String SHA1(String text) {
    Log.d("SHA1:::", ":" + text);
    try {

        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),
                0, text.length());
        byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
        System.out.println(("SHA1:::::" + sha1hash));
        System.out.println(toHex(sha1hash));
        return toHex(sha1hash);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {

    if (buf == null) return "";

    int l = buf.length;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * l);

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }

    return result.toString();

}
```

But i am getting different results from code and manual sha1sum.Please suggest me how can i do this..

Comment: Are you sure, the text in the file is encoded in iso-8859-1?

Comment: content is encoded in UTF-8,I tried with that one also.. but no use..

Comment: Also note that `text.length()` is not necessarily the number of bytes in the `text.getBytes()` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct which i posted in the question.The sha1sum of the android code is correct where as the manual sha1sum is wrong.I taken the response of the URL from the mozilla web browser,the browser truncates the last white lines.. so the sha1sum is incorrect.Now i am using the Chrome for response thing,sha1sum is same as the android code sha1sum.

Note:Please use the chrome response so that we can get the same sha1sum..

Comment: "The code is correct": well, kind of. With ISO-8859-1 you are lucky, because one character is mapped to one byte. This is not the case with UTF-8 for example. (See also my comment on the question).